# anyway to use 'name reference' of linq to sql entiity classes and members?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to Use something like collections

```
from m in myDataContext.Customers select m.("FirstName")
```

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, you want to provide a string and have it select that column.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes, exactly i want to retrieve field by string variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are looking for dynamic LINQ

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: thank you Pleun . I wonder why this extension not included in .net!